# At what radius from nucleus does an electron reach the speed of light?

Tags: electrons, speed-of-light, protons

Let's forget about the quantum knowledge here.

Lets say that we just want to know what speed an electron can get, 
when falling straight on to a nucleus.
It does not miss the nucleus and start spinning around.
It goes straight at the nucleus.

Just think of charge and radius of proton and alpha particle and mass.

At what radius from the nucleus, lets say a proton or an alpha particle, 
does it get  90%, 99% and 99.999% of speed of light?

Does it reach the speed of light?

Or at what radius does the mass of the electron get so heavy (because of its speed), that it does not accelerate any more?

Is there a radius, where the mass/energy increase just as much as the the acceleration increase, that it can not get closer to the nucleus?

Does it ever balance out in this Newtonian world?

--

Comment: Taking this as a Newtonian mechanics question (i.e. forgetting relativity as well as QM so that the question makes sense), you are missing some initial conditions.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that the electron starts at rest at infinity, then its kinetic energy is equal to (-1 times) its potential energy in the electric field of the nucleus. In other words:

$$K=\frac{kZe^2}{r}$$

for a nucleus with atomic number $Z$, where $k$ is Coulomb's constant. The relativistic kinetic energy is defined as:

$$K=E-m_ec^2=(\gamma-1)m_ec^2$$

where $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}$ is the Lorentz factor. Based on this formula, it should be easy to see that getting to $v/c=1$ requires infinite kinetic energy, and so is impossible for any massive object. If we solve this equation for $v/c$, we get:

$$\frac{v}{c}=\frac{\sqrt{K^2+2Km_ec^2}}{K+m_ec^2}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{k^2Z^2e^4}{r^2}+\frac{2kZe^2m_ec^2}{r}}}{\frac{kZe^2}{r}+m_ec^2}$$

If we simplify a bit, we get:

$$\frac{v}{c}=\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{2m_ec^2}{kZe^2}r}}{1+\frac{m_ec^2}{kZe^2}r}$$

We just have to solve this for $r$ now:

$$r=\frac{kZe^2}{m_ec^2}\frac{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}+1-(v/c)^2}{(v/c)^2}$$

And now we plug things in. $m_ec^2=8.2\times 10^{-14}$ J, and $ke^2=2.3\times 10^{-28}$ J$\cdot$m, so:

- for $v/c=0.9$ we have $r=(2.2Z)$ fm,
- for $v/c=0.99$ we have $r=(0.46Z)$ fm, and
- for $v/c=0.99999$ we have $r=(0.012Z)$ fm.

A proton has $Z=1$ and $r\approx 1$ fm, so the last two speeds are impossible, as the electron is already inside the proton at that point. For a lead-208 nucleus, $Z=82$ and $r\approx 7$ fm, so two of the three speeds are possible.

Comment: So why doesn't this electron obey the rules of the quantum world?

Comment: At what radius does the mass of the electron get so heavy (because of its speed), that it does not accelerate any more?

Comment: @Gert Beats me, it was an assumption I was asked to make.

Comment: @Jlivingstonsg The mass of the electron never changes. The relation between its total energy and its speed changes, in such a way that adding more and more energy will increase the speed less and less. But adding more energy will _always_ accelerate the electron, even if only by a tiny amount.

Comment: Ok.  So what speed and mass/energy does the electron have,  when it reach the radius (5.29177210903(80)×10−11 m) it have in Hydrogen and Helium?

Comment: @Jlivingstonsg The mass of the electron doesn't change. It's the same as when it started. As for the speed, you should be able to calculate that yourself from the material given in this answer.